# Adding picture linked to feature in QGIS report layout

Tags: qgis, image, layouts, dynamic

I'm trying to make a report in QGIS, in the attribute table of my layer, I have a column named *"picture1"* filled with the relative path of a picture, that illustrate the feature.

In the report, I did a "Field group section" with my layer and a map controlled by report. Now I would like to add the picture related to each feature, in order to have one page by feature with its location and its picture. With the button next to "image source", I tried to choose the "field type" that identify each feature and also to write `concat(@project_folder, '/', "picture1.jpg")` in the expression, but neither of them worked...

Do you have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Your `"picture1.jpg"` should either refer to a column (e.g. `"image"`) with double quotes, or a static string (like `'picture1.jpg'`) with single quotes

Comment: Yes, sorry I wrote the wrong expression here, what I tried was : concat(@project_folder,'/' , "picture1" ) because "picture1" is my column's name with the paths to the images. But when I write that or when I check the field type nothing appears in the blank below "image source"...

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, check my answer. I've almost never used Reports before though so not sure if this fits your situation

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to add the image by going to the Field Group Section and clicking <kbd>Edit</kbd> next to Include Body, and if the little grey tab above the layout shows you're in the Body: Group element, then you can access the fields of your Group layer for the image source field list, etc.

[image]

Keep in mind though it doesn't seem to work properly at first - at least for me I needed to test export a pdf before it seemed to actually place values in the text boxes/image in the image item, etc.